# Resultant of the additions of two vectors in Polar Space/Coordinations in python

Tags: vector, geometry, polar-coordinates

Consider a vector, from the origin, in polar coordinates.

```
(r1, phi1)
```

and then another vector added to that vector;

```
(r2, phi2)
```

Then with the resultant vector you trace out a triangle. The value of top angle (theta) can be calculated with phi1 and phi2, and the cosine rule can be used to determine the magnitude of R and the sine rule can be calculated to work out the angle of R.

It becomes very tricky because depending on the value of phi2, the equations to calculate theta changes.

Is there any other solution that neatly solves this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video explaining the math for adding vectors.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5by-REDgyg0

Once you have all two lower angles, the sum of the angles in a triangle is 180.